# How to add current price line on hover?

Tags: highcharts

I found a plugin that is able to show current price line on highstock candlestick chart, but it only displays the latest data.

I have tried to find a way to display the horizontal price line when user hovers over the data.

I thought it might be related to tooltip event, but I have no idea how to do it.

Could someone give me a hint? Thanks,

```
 tooltop:{
             formatter: function () {

            }
        },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RolandBanguiran/nf7ne/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a couple of ways to achieve that. Problem is a little missing description (do you want to display current price on hover, or actually hovered value?).

Anyway, the easiest way would be to enable [crosshairs](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#tooltip.crosshairs): [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/tooltip/crosshairs-xy/).

Another way is to add/remove `plotLine` on `mouseOver` event for `series.point`, [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nf7ne/48/) and code:

```
            point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function() {
                         var chart = this.series.chart;

                        chart.yAxis[0].removePlotLine("tooltip-line");
                        chart.yAxis[0].addPlotLine({
                            width: 2,
                            color: "black",
                            id: "tooltip-line",
                            value: this.y
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
```

If you want to hide that line, use `mouseOut` event and simply remove `plotLine` like above.

Third option bases on the above one - in case you want to display current price instead of hovered one. In such case, change value for the `plotLine`, [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nf7ne/49/) and code:

```
            point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function() {
                         var chart = this.series.chart;

                        chart.yAxis[0].removePlotLine("tooltip-line");
                        chart.yAxis[0].addPlotLine({
                            width: 2,
                            color: "black",
                            id: "tooltip-line",
                            value: this.series.yData[this.series.yData.length - 1][0]
                        });
                    },
                    mouseOut: function() {
                        this.series.yAxis.removePlotLine("tooltip-line");
                    }
                }
            }
```

**Extra tip:** 
Check out more option for `plotLines` in the [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.plotLines) (like dash style, or label).